# What does @_ -1 mean in Perl?

Tags: php, perl, arrays

I'm trying to translate a Perl script to PHP and I'm having trouble with some Perl things. For instance, what does `@_ -1` mean? And how do I write it in PHP?

The whole function is as follows:

```
sub variance {
    my $sum = sum_squares (@_);
    my $deg = @_ - 1;
    return $sum/$deg;
}
```

---

Ok, all the subroutines are as follows:

```
sub mean { # mean of values in an array
  my $sum = 0 ;
  foreach my $x (@_) {
    $sum += $x ;
  }
  return $sum/@_ ;
}

sub sum_squares { # sum of square differences from the mean
  my $mean = mean (@_) ;
  my $sum_squares = 0 ;
  foreach my $x (@_) {
    $sum_squares += ($x - $mean) ** 2 ;
  }
  return $sum_squares ;
}

sub variance { # variance of values in an array
  my $sum_squares = sum_squares (@_) ;
  my $deg_freedom = @_ - 1 ;
  return $sum_squares/$deg_freedom ;
}

sub median { # median of values in an array
  my @sorted = sort {$a <=> $b} (@_) ;
  if (1 == @sorted % 2) # Odd number of elements
    {return $sorted[($#sorted)/2]}
  else                   # Even number of elements
    {return ($sorted[($#sorted-1)/2]+$sorted[($#sorted+1)/2]) / 2}
}

sub histogram { # Counts of elements in an array
  my %histogram = () ;
  foreach my $value (@_) {$histogram{$value}++}
  return (%histogram) ;
}
```

Please bear with me because its my first time with Perl. From what I've seen (tested), the right answer in this case is the one of David Dorward. I do have another question regarding this set of subroutines that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354110/what-does-histogramvalue-mean-in-perl).

Comment: Equal but not equivalent. It's wise to write the one you mean. If you mean "one less than the number of things in `@_`" write `@_ - 1`. If you mean "the last index in `@_`" write `$#_`.

Comment: (Technically, if you use the deprecated and thoroughly evil `$[`, the two might not even be equal. But don't do that.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case,`@_` is the arguments passed to the subroutine, as a list.

Taken in scalar context, it is the number of elements in that list.

So if you call: `variance('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');`, `$deg` will be 3.

Comment: `@_` is an array, not a list.

Comment: To be pedantic: @_ is an array containing the arguments that get passed to the subroutine as a list.

Answer (score 7):

Like already said, it is the array of arguments passed to the function. It's equivalent in PHP would be

- [`func_get_args()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) — Returns an array comprising a function's argument list
- [`func_num_args()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) — Returns the number of arguments passed to the function

The entire function would be

```
function variance() {
    $sum = sum_squares(func_get_args());
    $deg = func_num_args() - 1;
    return $sum/$deg;
}
// echo variance(1,2,3,4,5); // 13.75 (55/4)
```

---

For [`sum_squares`](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares), there is no native function in PHP. Assuming it does what the name implies, e.g. raising each argument to the power of 2 and then summing the result, you could implement it as

```
function sum_squares(array $args) {
    return array_reduce(
        $args, create_function('$x, $y', 'return $x+$y*$y;'), 0
    );
}
// echo sum_squares( array(1,2,3,4,5) ); // 55
```

Replace [`create_function`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) with a proper [lambda](http://de.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) if you are on PHP5.3

Comment: This function throws back an error. (See the whole code above)

Comment: @Alex what error? call to undefined function sum_squares? Of course it does. It's a userland function and you have to define it somewhere. See update above for a possible implementation.

Comment: @Gordon yes, that one. I defined it.
Here is the php code:

 function mean($array) {
  return array_sum($array) / count($array);
 }
 
 function sum_squares($array) {
  $sum  = 0;
  $mean = mean($array);
  foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
   $sum += pow($val - $mean, 2);
  }
  return $sum;
 }

Using these functions, your version of the variance function throws back an error.

Comment: @Alex I would highly appreciate if you would add the error message. Just saying it doesn't work or it throws an error tells nothing about what might be wrong. When I use the functions you gave in the comment above, `variance(1,2,3,4,5)` will return 2.5, without an error.

Comment: True, my bad! Here it is:
Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in Document on line 20.
Line 20 is this: $sum += pow($val - $mean, 2);

Comment: @Alex this is a line from your own `sum_squares` function. It is not the `variance` function that is causing the error. The `variance` function is functionally equivalent to it's Perl counterpart as given in your question. You are probably invoking it `variance(array(1,2,3,4,5))`, which will obviously cause the error you mention because func_get_args() will return **an array comprising a function's argument list**, e.g. `array(0 => array(1,2,3,4,5))`

Comment: I get it. The idea that bothers me is that using the functions I wrote I get the same result as in Perl, BUT they are not an identical translation from Perl, like yours is. Thus, I don't know which way to go: adapt the functions in PHP or translate them as they are in Perl.

Comment: @Alex PHP and Perl both have their unique quirks. I wouldn't bother about *how* the functions are implemented in Perl as long as the desired input and output is correct. Port the functionality, not the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It's the number of arguments, passed to the `variance` subroutine minus one (or index of the last element in the `@_` array). `@_` is used in scalar context here.

Answer (score 2):

@_ is the incoming parameter to the sub, but referred in scalar context is the number of parameters.

In php will be something like:

```
function variance() {
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    $sum = sum_squares($arguments);
    $deg = sizeof($arguments);
    return $sum/$deg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@_` is the list of parameters being paassed into the subroutine. When you use it in a non-scalar context such as:

```
sum_squares (@_)
```

you get the list, so presumably that would return the sum of the squares of all the numbers in that list (see comment below however).

When used in a scalar context, you get the length so in your case it would be the number of items in the `$@` function list.

So your variance function is probably (I say probably since I don't have access to the `sum_squares` source code) calculating:

```
variance = arr[0]^2 + arr[1]^2 + ... + arr[N-1]^2
           --------------------------------------
                            N - 1
```

on the array of values being passed into your function.

I have to say that my understanding of variance is at odds with that (thouugh it's been a while since I did any stats). I'm pretty certain it's supposed to involve the sum of the squares of the *differences* between the values and the mean, *not* the values themselves. I suspect there's more happening inside `sum_squares` than its simple name implies.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement the other answers, the `@_` [Special Variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) is described in the free official Perl online documentation (along with other variables):

> Within a subroutine the array @_
>   contains the parameters passed to that
>   subroutine. See perlsub.

Answer (score 0):

> In function @_ will have list of function argument which is passed to the function  . 
>   Actually when we are trying to assign the list value to the scalar , it will assign the length of the array. 
>   And Here -1 is for accessing the last element of the @_ array

```
sub test 
{ 
my $count = @_ ; # Now it will assign the number of function arguments 
# Because we are trying to assign as a scalar. 
>print "Output:$count\n" ; # Output : 4 
($count ) = @_   # Now it will assign the first element of the functions 
print "Output:$count\n" ; #  OUtput: 10 
# Because we are trying to assign as list values , So ,list as only one variable  . 
# So , first element gets assigned. 
} 
&test ( 10,20,30,40 ) ;
```